# How do I set "Cookie" header in a new request from "Set-Cookie" header response for a SOAP client in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm integrating my WPF application with 2 WCF applications (one is an "Authentication Application" and the other is a "real" application that requires authentication). The "Authentication Application" returns 3 `Set-Cookie` headers, and I need to add them to the request header of the "real" application. But I'm unsure of how to get those headers (only the result) I can get:

```
AuthenticationApplicationService.SoapClient authenticationSoapClient = new AuthenticationApplicationService.SoapClient("AuthenticationApplicationServiceSoap");
bool loggedInSuccess = await authenticationSoapClient.PerformLoginAsync();
// how do I get the cookie headers from this call and set them on the next?

RealService.SoapClient realSoapClient = new RealService.SoapClient("RealServiceSoap");
realSoapClient.PostAsync("hello");
```

That first call to `PerformLoginAsync` returns true or false for successfully logged in, and the headers inclue `Set-Cookie`. How can I grab those headers and set `Cookie` headers on the next request to `PostAsync`?

If there are further questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use OperationContext, it has properties that could send cookie.
To enable cookie , you should set the allowcookie property to true in your binding configuration.

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AuthSoap" allowCookies="true" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:63599/Auth" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="AuthSoap" contract="Auth.AuthSoap" name="AuthSoap" />
</client>
```

Then you could call the login method as follows.

```
 Auth.AuthSoapClient authSoapClient = new Auth.AuthSoapClient();
        using (new OperationContextScope(authSoapClient.InnerChannel))
        {
// please put the call of method in OperationContextScope
            authSoapClient.Login("admin", "admin");

          // the following code get the set-cookie header passed by server

            HttpResponseMessageProperty response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[
                HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            string header  = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
          // then you could save it some place  
        }
```

After you get the cookie, you should  set it in your header every time you call your method.

```
 Auth.AuthSoapClient authSoapClient = new Auth.AuthSoapClient();
        using (new OperationContextScope(authSoapClient.InnerChannel))
        {
             //below code sends the cookie back to server

            HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Headers["Cookie"] =  please get the cookie you stored when you   successfully logged in               
 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[
                HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;
// please put the call of method in OperationContextScope
            string msg = authSoapClient.GetMsg();
        }
```

If you feel it troublesome to send cookie every time after successfully logging in. You could consider using MessageInspector, refer to the link's last piece of code 
https://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/